# After copying ADT Bundles from one ubuntu machine to another eclipse doesn't open

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-ndk, adt

I have adt bundle installed and updated (sdk, ndk, eclipse) in my personal computer. Now I need to use another PC. So I thought instead of downloading all 35+ GB I should move them from the older PC to the newer one. Both the PC have ubuntu 14.04(64 bit), Oracle JDK 1.8.0_20(64 bit). Now after copying the files the eclipse in the second PC is not working. Any suggestions ?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be due to a number of things:

- If the installation directories are not identical on each system, that could cause a problem.  Eclipse often saves settings in configuration files that contain full pathnames.
- Environment variables - Eclipse and/or Java might have a dependency on an environment variable (JAVA_HOME, PATH), that is either not set or is incorrect on the new system.

This sort of thing can be time-consuming to debug.  My suggestion is to take the safe (but slow) path of downloading and re-installing ADT.